# Java to PHP: encryption of base 64 secret key with RSA

Tags: java, php, encryption, rsa, phpseclib

I am trying to replicate the following java function in PHP.

**Java Code:**

```
public static String signWithRSA(SecretKey value, Path keyPath) throws InvalidPublicKeyException {
        try(FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(keyPath.toFile())){
            CertificateFactory f = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate)f.generateCertificate(fin);
            PublicKey pk = certificate.getPublicKey();
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pk);
            byte [] appKeyBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(value.getEncoded());
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(appKeyBytes));
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException
                | IllegalBlockSizeException
                | BadPaddingException
                | NoSuchPaddingException
                | InvalidKeyException
                | CertificateException
                | IOException e) {
            throw new InvalidPublicKeyException("Invalid Certificate Provided: "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

What I understand from this code is,

```
1. Getting Certificate from File,
2. Get PublicKey 
3. RSA encode the PublicKey
4. Base64encode the PrivateKey
5. RSA Encode the encodedPrivateKey with encodedPublicKey and retrn the Base64EncodedValue

I have tried with the following code: (PHP 7.2, PhpSecLib)
```

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use phpseclib\Crypt\RSA;
use phpseclib\Math\BigInteger;

$testCertLocation ="resource/public.cer";

$pub_key = openssl_get_publickey(file_get_contents($testCertLocation));

$keyData = openssl_pkey_get_details($pub_key);

$mykey_n= ($keyData['rsa']['n']);
$mykey_e = ($keyData['rsa']['e']);

$mykey_n_h = bin2hex($mykey_n);
$mykey_e_h = bin2hex($mykey_e);


$rsa = new RSA();

$r = $rsa->loadkey(
    array(
      'e' => new BigInteger($mykey_e_h, 16),
      'n' => new BigInteger($mykey_n_h, 16)
    ),
    3 
);

$providedEncodedKey = "guRPIRvUYvgqRL5AaLuDYl69dOhVH8+R763oM2Y6iXg=";
$plaintext = $providedEncodedKey;

$rsa->setEncryptionMode(RSA::ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);
$ciphertext = $rsa->encrypt($plaintext);
echo base64_encode($ciphertext) . "<br>";

echo $rsa->verify($plaintext, $ciphertext) ? 'verified' : 'unverified';
```

I am facing the following issues:

1. The ciphertext keps on changing with each refresh (i think it should not change for a given constant. I might be wrong though.)
2. It is not matching with the provided sample (for given plaintext). 
   The provided values is:

```
dWXiHslSGaKwQB6D93Q2lBNOl4x+N73wtDEU5E39IM3c0Cd2HrFO9EB9ZCK+qyUxU/zdEdx2GYw5a0mV9OXPwLONJYBFuN
ApHRyxRQAS8fLwtuSUKWzygsMPekd+AhvuPUlJO+9Qfutq2igy+kCNVe0lJWZqOY4l7FNQGd3XdDapRaNhgiFw3VV1O00d
elrCM9rKCaDUN6HFAmLy11zK/vMbXmy0YA8PUoX1mJvaxQwFEQWvJhG++NRQL3KtHWNPDKA0irkWoZqpZF/XyUS1zmXuMI
3SZ7c2bG6rHFebby1t/TVr3jcHSwKmLVMGIJi4QtdWRT6Rjl3FnN4DVunPbg==

The Certificate details are as follows:
N: ceeb7b9b5cc4c84e5a050d4082fa59c19a23583a2d861de03415a36f6660feed43a2d6047fe0d42513a996691d7
6e499c240005afe5a1ad01a677327b6de049740fd319acbff15bfd56a27f23b1c648c1cd6f9533fb20387f88c0cb92
6ff1f5eb87bbe79a03803072158a54fe91a2ccaf4227c1ec682e71d35f5f711bf0278f1ee1007d77f7f24df4378967
9d512221837c0e100d6ed6d699749923530c299df0814ea60a94006f747ca6ff2cb992233d67aebb1681c815c5fed1
c5d2c3c1b3c25241276d7f2d59a07d9845f9c5e81cdd7c5269038a35cd1cfd990af953fc8f5531aabdb30ed524f46a
e6a03f024325069078530e1ff8c2c069373d57e45b5f5
E: 010001

The result which I am getting is ($ciphertext) as follows:
sbQK1CBP06ByLZyJObc3bm6EAyfHvgAPvPMkKy+RCFqQiW9maKc9qqwliYgLYtNhF6aDCrEv/jtTHPZn3YqDbVnIXGcG63
dcn/YK9NVkHj+f4aRSPO99mAUMDeSjTkiMgfhIGO8yMWp7SvFL8tynFP/+j4W5KkyS+vOkwocCy1OdK3VN5u0fnFPUUFMH
/WEodMFndz5fF49vI9ZGioIge75kgTxvKzwroQ+BRML59ZL+PNM1M5QbAqVnyF4KE7iL1Lj/KvKMdnLkU6z/8Atpnw7jz1
8DRna5ztQpGKWGkUs1IiEYAZmRTl77FXfQfDeGOtEl38V9pmwCtGPUHf6Ctw==

unverified
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are not signing with RSA, you are encrypting. You're using the public key after all. And you are encrypting a *secret* key, not a *private* key; it makes no sense to encrypt a *private* key for anybody else as you don't share private information. Encrypting keys is actually called *key wrapping* and there are special Java methods that the code fails to use.

Comment: PKCS#1 uses randomized padding so it will *always* return a different ciphertext by design. You can verify by simply *decrypting* with the private key. Signature generation / verification uses a different padding scheme and will always fail to verify encryption, even if you use the keys correctly - which you don't.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes thanks for reviewing the code. Can you suggest what needs to be changed in PHP code in order to work like Java Code.

Comment: First try and cross-decrypt your ciphertext values. There may not be anything wrong. The main thing that is currently not correct is the way that you test **if** something is wrong - both comparison of the values and verification *should* fail.

Comment: Just a couple of additional points. For maximum interoperability always specify the full *algorithm/mode/padding* string to `Cipher.getInstance()`. Also, there is no benefit to base64 encoding the secret key prior to RSA encrypting it. There is no harm either, it's just unnecessary work.

Comment: I am still not sure in which part of php code I am making mistake

Comment: @MaartenBodewes second comment explains that you are not necessarily making a mistake. Encryption of the same value should **always** return a different result because of the padding. As Maarten said, the only way to know if it's correct is to *decrypt* the value and check the result.

Comment: ok, Thanks for the suggestion, I will try it today and revert.

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting any success, the result is not correct.

Comment: I may give this another look tomorrow.